# How to sort Datatable based string array in jquery?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I need to sort datatable based on string array. Datatable "Officer Position" column need to sort like array order. example first row "president" 2nd row "Vice President", etc.

```
array = ["President","Vice President","Membership Chair","Secretary","Treasurer"];
```

[image]

code;

```
var tmpV = $(this).parent().parent().find("select").val();
        addTable.row.add([
                            searchedItem.FirstName,
                            searchedItem.LastName,
                            searchedItem.Id,
                            tmpV,
                            searchedItem.DegreeLevel,
                            searchedItem.DegreeProgram,

                            '<button type="button" data_uid="' + searchedItem.Id + '" name="deleteRowBtn" class="btn btn-primary" >Delete</button>',

                            getOrderNum(tmpV)
                        ]).draw(false);
```

Comment: I would suggest posting a bit more code related to the database table so we can make suggestions.

Comment: @TanveerBadar The title of the question asks how to perform the task in C#, yet you removed the `c#` tag. Please comment on why you think that is appropriate.

Comment: Note that there are `DataTable`s, which are related to ADO.NET and are .NET objects, and there is `DataTables` a jQuery plugin which a helps create grids for web pages. Both allow for sorting (one on the backend, one on the front). You may want to edit your question to make it clear where exactly you want help.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it sounds like you're asking how to extend the jQuery DataTables plugin to use custom sort logic for a particular column.  Is that correct?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I have changed title

Comment: If you're looking to extend jQuery DataTables with custom sort logic, this looks like the place to start: https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/  The page links to multiple examples of plugins which create custom "sort types", and it sounds like you'd just need to make your own such plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve this using  [enum plugin](https://datatables.net/blog/2016-06-16).

```
 $(document).ready( function () {

  $.fn.dataTable.enum( ["President", "Vice President", "Membership Chair", "Secretary", "Treasurer", "Member"] );
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [Array.Sort]
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_Sort_System_Array_System_Array_System_Collections_IComparer_

This will sort one Array, by the given order in the other Array.
You just need to define, which column to use for comparison.

Comment: Looks like you did not get my point. I need to sort datatable based give array. first row "president" 2nd row "Vice President", etc...

Comment: you are right, it's a little different. For you solution I recommend you change your array of string to an array of tuples.
`array = [{"President", 0},{"Vice President", 1},{"Membership", 2}, {Chair, 3}","{Secretary, 4}",{"Treasurer, 5}]. `
Than it's a simple JOIN with Orderby.
(If you have influence on the data model, of course an enum would have been better in first place, instead of this string, this safes you all the trouble).